# Updating all rows of a column returns only last value in foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, database, foreach

I want to update a specific column of my database with a foreach loop. But it updates only the last element of the array in the column

```
foreach ($_POST['matricule'] as $matricule) {
    $query_update = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE dates_precedentes SET matricule = ?");
    $query_update -> execute([$matricule]);    
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyqOj.png) of my table.

Output of `print_r($_POST['matricule'])`

[image]

Comment: you need to add the where condition in query otherwise all rows will be updated with same value

Comment: If you don't use a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE`, every rows will be updated

Comment: _Small Point_ The Prepare should be outside the loop, you dont need to prepare the same query each time round the loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly one can execute many time the same prepared query with differents parameters ?

Comment: @Cid yes thats why I said it could be put above the loop and done only once

Comment: As @Cid said, you are updating ALL the row in the table each time round the loop, so the last loop will set all rows to the value of the last occurance in `$_POST['matricule']`

Comment: I want to update each row of the column with each element of the array $_POST['matricule]

Comment: Do you have anouther field in $_POST that contains the `id` of the row to update. Using just the `$_POST['matricule']` make no sense